# Apache Ignite nodes fail: Failed to read magic header

Tags: java, ignite

Apache Ignite servers deployed on two machines automatically shut down. No concrete clue in logs. I am able to see following warning message in log file :

`[00:35:14,047][WARNING][tcp-disco-sock-reader-#86379%null%][TcpDiscoverySpi] Failed to read magic header (too few bytes received) [rmtAddr=/10.96.36.48:47830, locAddr=/10.96.36.48:47500]`

How can i debug and solve this issue ?

Configuration:

```
    <bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
                <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
                <property name="cacheConfiguration">
                                <list>
                                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                                                <property name="name" value="xyxCache" />
                                                <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="FULL_SYNC" />
                                                <property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED" />
                                                <property name="rebalanceMode" value="SYNC" />
                                                <property name="readFromBackup" value="true" />
                                                <property name="startSize" value="150000" />
                                                <property name="evictionPolicy">
                                                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.eviction.lru.LruEvictionPolicy">
                                                                <property name="maxSize" value="1000000" />
                                                        </bean>
                                                </property>
                                        </bean>
                                </list>
                        </property>
<property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <value>10.96.36.48:47500</value>
                                <value>10.96.36.214:47500</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 4):

Check which process on 10.96.36.48 machine binded to port 47830.
For example, `netstat -lnp` will list the pid and process name next to each listening port. This will work under Linux.

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens if some other application like telnet connects to the port.

Please share your configuration and setup details, without which it is not possible to answer any further.

Comment: configuration details appended in question itself.